# Ordering bars according to the values of y

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Using the code below, I have created the below chart. To make it easier for people to see the pattern, I'd like to order states from left to right according to the y values (Dx) by age 65.

Thanks,

NM

## Here is my data:

structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("30", "50", "65"), class = "factor"), Dx = c(3.057, 7.847, 17.157, 2.851, 8.861, 21.885, 2.521, 7.889, 21.328), PopName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AK", "AL", "AR"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
library(tidyverse)

```
library(tidyverse)

   CAPS_2019 %>% 
  group_by(Age, PopName) %>% 
  mutate(PopName1 = sum(Dx)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(PopName, PopName1), y = Dx, fill = factor(as.character(Age)))) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  theme_classic()+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x = "State", y = "Deaths (%)", caption = (""), face = "bold", fill = "Age")
```

[image]

Comment: Can't replicate your example because I don't have your data. But you can convert the variables that you map to x and y to factors whose levels correspond to the order that you want. Useful functions are `factor()` and `fct_reorder()`.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("30", "50", "65"), class = "factor"), Dx = c(3.057, 
7.847, 17.157, 2.851, 8.861, 21.885, 2.521, 7.889, 21.328), PopName = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AK", "AL", "AR"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Change the dataframe to `CAPS_2019_data` e.g. : `CAPS_2019_data %>% 
  group_by(Age, P.......`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2** Try this in your new dataset Age and Popname are already factors. So maybe this should work as expected:

```
CAPS_2019_data %>% 
  group_by(Age, PopName) %>% 
  mutate(PopName1 = sum(Dx)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(PopName, PopName1), y = Dx, fill = Age)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  theme_classic()+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x = "State", y = "Deaths (%)", caption = (""), face = "bold", fill = "Age")
```

**Update:**
data:

```
CAPS_2019 <- structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("30", "50", "65"), class = "factor"), Dx = c(3.057, 
7.847, 17.157, 2.851, 8.861, 21.885, 2.521, 7.889, 21.328), PopName = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AK", "AL", "AR"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

1. To get the stacks ordered use `position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)`
2. To order y axis do some preprocessing with `group_by` and `sum` and use `fct_reorder` from `forcats` package (it is in `tidyverse`)

```
library(tidyverse)

CAPS_2019 %>% 
  group_by(Age, PopName) %>% 
  mutate(PopName1 = sum(Dx)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(PopName, PopName1), y = Dx, fill = factor(as.character(Age)))) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  theme_classic()+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x = "State", y = "Deaths (%)", caption = (""), face = "bold", fill = "Age")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful! How can I order states from top to bottom according to the y values (Dx) by age 65?

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: What was with the answer?

Comment: Thanks but the code do not return the plot you shared! The code returns the original plot which states were ordered alphabetically!

Comment: Unbelievable I will check.

Comment: The provided code with the provided data gives exactly the plot I have posted. Have you loaded the correct dataframe? and tidyverse? I updated the data I used!

Comment: Yes! Everything is the same as yours but the plot! I am confused too!

Comment: You should load library(tidyverse)

Comment: Yes I did! Please let me update my question so we can see what is going on!

Comment: You have a new dataframe name `CAPS_2019_data`

Comment: I reupdated my question though It does not make any differences!

Comment: I have added a new possible solution in my answer. Please try and tell me.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting the same plot I shared in my question!

Comment: Maybe close and restart R

Comment: Still not working!

Comment: could you post your session info please

Comment: Sure! How can I get my session info!

Comment: Just type `sessionInfo()` in the command line and hit enter. Copy the output and add it to your question as update.

Comment: R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.6